# MySQL: Using ORDER BY and UNION

Tags: mysql, e-commerce, opencart, mysql-workbench

Please take a look at the following query:

```
INSERT INTO product_filter (product_id,filter_id)
SELECT product_id,
(CASE WHEN price < 100 then 1
WHEN price >= 100 AND price < 500 then 2
WHEN price >= 500 AND price < 1000 then 3
WHEN price >= 1000 AND price < 1500 then 4
WHEN price >= 1500 AND price < 2000 then 5
WHEN price >= 2000 AND price < 2500 then 50
WHEN price >= 2500 AND price < 3000 then 6
ELSE 51 END) AS filter_id
FROM product_special
ORDER BY priority DESC, date_end DESC
LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT product_id,
(CASE WHEN price < 100 then 1
WHEN price >= 100 AND price < 500 then 2
WHEN price >= 500 AND price < 1000 then 3
WHEN price >= 1000 AND price < 1500 then 4
WHEN price >= 1500 AND price < 2000 then 5
WHEN price >= 2000 AND price < 2500 then 50
WHEN price >= 2500 AND price < 3000 then 6
ELSE 51 END) AS filter_id
FROM product WHERE product_id not IN
(SELECT product_id FROM product_special)
```

This is what the query is supposed to do:

- select all special prices from the product_special table and depending on the price, associate them to different price filters
- every product can have multiple special prices, so just pick the one that has higher priority and will last longer
- select all regular prices from the product table (only those that don't have special price in the product_special table) and depending on the price, associate them to different price filters

Error I'm receiving:

`Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY`

Sample Data sets:

[Products](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/b472229f)

[Specials](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/0bc7a65c)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `UNION` queries with `LIMIT` or `ORDER BY` for each separate query then you need to organize your queries using brackets like

```
(query 1 with limit order by ) 
 UNION 
(query 1 with limit order by )
```

Your above query can be written as to avoid this error

```
INSERT INTO product_filter (product_id,filter_id)
(
SELECT product_id,
(CASE WHEN price < 100 then 1
WHEN price >= 100 AND price < 500 then 2
WHEN price >= 500 AND price < 1000 then 3
WHEN price >= 1000 AND price < 1500 then 4
WHEN price >= 1500 AND price < 2000 then 5
WHEN price >= 2000 AND price < 2500 then 50
WHEN price >= 2500 AND price < 3000 then 6
ELSE 51 END) AS filter_id
FROM product_special
ORDER BY priority DESC, date_end DESC
LIMIT 1 )
UNION
(SELECT product_id,
(CASE WHEN price < 100 then 1
WHEN price >= 100 AND price < 500 then 2
WHEN price >= 500 AND price < 1000 then 3
WHEN price >= 1000 AND price < 1500 then 4
WHEN price >= 1500 AND price < 2000 then 5
WHEN price >= 2000 AND price < 2500 then 50
WHEN price >= 2500 AND price < 3000 then 6
ELSE 51 END) AS filter_id
FROM product WHERE product_id not IN
(SELECT product_id FROM product_special)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, the error is now gone. I just don't know why the query is not doing what it's supposed to do. [Website](http://www.belfurniture.com/sleepers)

Comment: @farjam can you provide the sample data set of both tables not whole dataset just a sample and the desired result set look like from `product_filter` after insertion that would be easy to see whats going on

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, I attached them to the question, thanks. They are CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a sub-query for the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in the first query.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO product_filter (product_id,filter_id)
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT product_id,
(CASE WHEN price < 100 then 1
WHEN price >= 100 AND price < 500 then 2
WHEN price >= 500 AND price < 1000 then 3
WHEN price >= 1000 AND price < 1500 then 4
WHEN price >= 1500 AND price < 2000 then 5
WHEN price >= 2000 AND price < 2500 then 50
WHEN price >= 2500 AND price < 3000 then 6
ELSE 51 END) AS filter_id
FROM product_special
ORDER BY priority DESC, date_end DESC
LIMIT 1) a
UNION
SELECT product_id,
(CASE WHEN price < 100 then 1
WHEN price >= 100 AND price < 500 then 2
WHEN price >= 500 AND price < 1000 then 3
WHEN price >= 1000 AND price < 1500 then 4
WHEN price >= 1500 AND price < 2000 then 5
WHEN price >= 2000 AND price < 2500 then 50
WHEN price >= 2500 AND price < 3000 then 6
ELSE 51 END) AS filter_id
FROM product WHERE product_id not IN
(SELECT product_id FROM product_special)
```

Comment: Thanks, the error is now gone. I just don't know why the query is not doing what it's supposed to do. [Example on my Website](http://www.belfurniture.com/sleepers)

Answer (score 0):

You should round brackets in order to use  ORDER/LIMIT on individual queries

For example

```
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ... ORDER BY field1 LIMIT 0, 1)
UNION   
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ...)
```

If you use Order BY outside brackets , it applies to UNIONED result